# C program to Ctypes Python

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying to call a simple function from a `C` program via `Ctypes` in Python (3.8.5).

 I however run into the `AttributeError`: `c_arr.so: undefined symbol: arrTest`. 
The goal is simply to test out a way to call a `C` function, compute an array and return a `struct` containing the pointer and the length of the array.

This is my C code `c_arr.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define arrTest main


struct ArrSz {
    int sz;
    float *pt;
};

struct ArrSz arrTest(int randnrsz){

    float test_arr[randnrsz];


    for (int i = 0; i < randnrsz; i++){
        test_arr[i] = rand() % 50;
    }


    struct ArrSz arrsz;
    arrsz.sz = sizeof(test_arr)/sizeof(test_arr[0]);
    arrsz.pt = test_arr;

    //printf("%d\n", arrsz.sz );
    //printf("%f\n", *arrsz.pt );

    return arrsz;
}
```

This is my Python code `py_arr.py` so far:

```py
from ctypes import *


libc = CDLL("./c_arr.so")
lib = libc.arrTest(c_int(5))

print(lib)
```

I compiled the code using:

```sh
gcc -shared -fPIC -o c_arr.so c_arr.c
```

Comment: Remove the definition of `arrTest` to `main` (`#define arrTest main`). This operates at a pre compilation level, so the symbol that ends up in the shared object is `_main` (not `_arrTest` as needed).

Comment: `test_arr` is a local variable, so won't be valid after the function returns.  Write code that works in C, called from C first; then worry about calling it from Python.  Allocate it on the heap, or pass in a pre-allocated structure to be filled out.